# Korean input (ibus-hangul) setup in Gnome 17.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, ibus

New install and trying to setup Korean language input via keyboard.

Under setting I installed Korean language input.  On terminal installed `ibus-hangul` and setup `ibus-setup` properly.  I am unable to install Input-Method Status Indicator, a gnome extension....  Starting the daemon with a command `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon -d` does not work.  No ibus choice on the bar.

Can someone help?

Comment: On Ubuntu GNOME it should not be needed to use `ibus-setup`, and the IBus daemon is started by default. Basically, all you should need to do is installing `ibus-hangul` and relogin/reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fcitx input method instead. It became the default in Xenial. Works like a charm in 16.04 for Korean.